# Compiling with libboost on raspberry pi - undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()

Tags: linux, c++11, boost, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to compile Ocelot tracker on raspberry pi 2 with OS Raspbian Jessie. I have installed libboost1.55-dev-all libraries from apt. 
When compiling I get multiple errors : "undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()".

I've been searching a lot and I found out that in most cases this is a problem with linker and something like -lboost_system should be put somewhere in the Makefile.am, but I'm not sure where to put it.

Also I'm not even sure this is the case here. Any pointer would be much appreciated, this is the first time I'm doing anything like this.

The complete log when compiling:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ocelot-1.0 $ make
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT config.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/config.Tpo -c -o config.o config.cpp
mv -f .deps/config.Tpo .deps/config.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT db.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/db.Tpo -c -o db.o db.cpp
mv -f .deps/db.Tpo .deps/db.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT events.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/events.Tpo -c -o events.o events.cpp
mv -f .deps/events.Tpo .deps/events.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT misc_functions.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/misc_functions.Tpo -c -o misc_functions.o misc_functions.cpp
mv -f .deps/misc_functions.Tpo .deps/misc_functions.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT ocelot.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/ocelot.Tpo -c -o ocelot.o ocelot.cpp
mv -f .deps/ocelot.Tpo .deps/ocelot.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT report.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/report.Tpo -c -o report.o report.cpp
mv -f .deps/report.Tpo .deps/report.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT response.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/response.Tpo -c -o response.o response.cpp
mv -f .deps/response.Tpo .deps/response.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT schedule.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/schedule.Tpo -c -o schedule.o schedule.cpp
mv -f .deps/schedule.Tpo .deps/schedule.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT site_comm.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/site_comm.Tpo -c -o site_comm.o site_comm.cpp
mv -f .deps/site_comm.Tpo .deps/site_comm.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT user.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/user.Tpo -c -o user.o user.cpp
mv -f .deps/user.Tpo .deps/user.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocelot\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocelot\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_BOOST=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_BOOST_SYSTEM=/\*\*/ -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBTCMALLOC=1 -I.   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -MT worker.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/worker.Tpo -c -o worker.o worker.cpp
worker.cpp: In member function ‘void worker::reap_peers()’:
worker.cpp:1028:49: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
    if (p->second.last_announced + peers_timeout < cur_time) {
                                                 ^
worker.cpp:1041:49: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
    if (p->second.last_announced + peers_timeout < cur_time) {
                                                 ^
mv -f .deps/worker.Tpo .deps/worker.Po
g++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors -pthread -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -g -O2 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ -o ocelot config.o db.o events.o misc_functions.o ocelot.o report.o response.o schedule.o site_comm.o user.o worker.o  -lboost_iostreams  -ltcmalloc -lmysqlpp -lmysqlclient -lev
site_comm.o: In function `error_code':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
site_comm.o: In function `get_system_category':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
site_comm.o:/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: more undefined references to `boost::system::system_category()' follow
site_comm.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
site_comm.o: In function `get_system_category':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
events.o: In function `get_system_category':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
events.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
events.o: In function `get_system_category':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
ocelot.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
ocelot.o: In function `get_system_category':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
schedule.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
schedule.o: In function `get_system_category':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
worker.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
worker.o: In function `get_system_category':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:412: recipe for target 'ocelot' failed
make: *** [ocelot] Error 1
```

Original Makefile.am

```
    ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

bin_PROGRAMS = ocelot ocelot_SOURCES = config.cpp config.h db.cpp db.h events.cpp events.h misc_functions.cpp misc_functions.h \
        ocelot.cpp ocelot.h report.cpp report.h response.cpp response.h \
        schedule.cpp schedule.h site_comm.cpp site_comm.h user.cpp user.h worker.cpp worker.h

AM_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -march=native -O2 -fvisibility=hidden
-fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-ident -Wall -Wfatal-errors $(PTHREAD_CFLAGS) $($ ocelot_LDADD = $(PTHREAD_LIBS) $(BOOST_IOSTREAMS_LIB) $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB) AM_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-O1
-Wl,--as-needed EXTRA_DIST = CHANGES LICENSE README.md ocelot.conf.dist dist-hook:
        touch ${distdir}/configure
        patch -p2 -d ${distdir} --no-backup-if-mismatch < ../dist.patch
```

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? I recently encountered some trouble with gcc 5 and boost-related autoconf macros.

Answer (score 1):

Boost-related files in *m4* folder may be too old, new versions can be downloaded from [boost base](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob_plain;f=m4/ax_boost_base.m4), [boost iostreams](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob_plain;f=m4/ax_boost_iostreams.m4), and [boost system](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob_plain;f=m4/ax_boost_system.m4).

After copying new versions of the files to folder *m4*, try `autoreconf -fvi` and then `configure` and `make`.

I managed to compile ocelot on debian jessie amd64 after updating those m4 files.